# tensorflow "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command". What does this mean? - Python v3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, installation, python-venv

I had trouble, initially, downloading tensorflow. Finally was able to do it, but now that I'm testing it in a virual environment, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.
```

The command I did before was supposed to verify if I installed it, and I saw it install. I even upgraded it to make sure. In the website though it told me to put this command in:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

I'm not sure why I got the error. I'm just starting to do ML, but to actually download/verify the download is being a pain. I looked on their website, but they don't list this error there. Was wondering if I could get help from the community.

Comment: Does your virtual environment have sufficient memory?

Comment: `python38-32`? Tensorflow requires 64-bit Python.

Comment: Selcuk, I wouldn't know how to check that.

Comment: 64 bit is installed. I dont know why its using the 32-bit, phd

Answer (score 0):

This link here may shed light on your issue:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/36

I know its for opencv but it may apply to your problem. I see Tensorflow so I assume that you may be using Anaconda to utilize GPU? If so then the link will tell you that you need to copy the python3.dll file into where your Anaconda3 install is located.